# How do I know if I have ifort installed on my Mac (Snow leopard)?

Tags: macos, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a program that need to be installed with the "gfortran/ifort" compiler.
I have a Mac OSX 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard). I know I have gcc installed, because I installed my self (from the gcc package inside the Xcode installer, so I did not have to install the whole xcode),  also after typing in the terminal "which gcc" I get the directory.

I also installed gfortran from gnu and after typing in the terminal "which gfortran" I get the directory.

However, since I am learning in this process, I am not sure if when I installed the gfortran the "ifort" is also installed or I have to install it my self as well. How can I check if ifort is install? If it is not install, where can I get it from for Snow Leopard?
Can it be installed if I installed the whole xcode and then the "command line tool"?

Answer (score 1):

`ifort` is the usual short name for the Intel Fortran compiler.  You know you have it installed if any of the following is true:

1. When you type `ifort` at a terminal command line you get a response such as `ifort: command line error: no files specified ...`
2. The XCode Build Settings for a Fortran project include lists for items such as `Intel Fortran Compiler ... Code Generation`.
3. You can find an executable called `ifort` somewhere on your disks; it's usual location is in `/usr/bin` but you might have installed it elsewhere.

Note that it is possible that you have it installed but can't use it because you don't have a licence. Intel Fortran costs money, the way to get a copy is to buy it either directly from Intel or from your local reseller.